# Site not deployed on AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have followed all instructions of deploying React app to AWS S3. Uploaded all files and folders in bucket, but, when clicked on site endpoint in Static Website Hosting shows blank page.What may be the cause? Please see following images for reference

All files and folders uploaded
[image]
Static Website Hosting in properties also updated
[image]
Public access also enabled
[image]
Bucket Policy also updated
[image]
Blank Page
[image]

This is all required for React App to deploy on AWS S3. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is inspector giving any errors?

Comment: Your browser has developer tools and a network monitor. Dig into those to see what content is actually being returned and what the HTTP request(s)/response(s) are.

Comment: @jarmod OK I discovered now that the error in console is 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching index.html works fine, but the various JavaScript files are all yielding 404.

The problem appears to be that your HTML is fetching resources as:

```
/WeatherApp/static/js/main.057efd26.chunk.js
```

but in the origin they are actually at:

```
/static/js/main.057efd26.chunk.js
```

Fix your index.html to refer to static resources rooted at `/static/`, not `/WeatherApp/static/`.

Answer (score 0):

1. In package.json file, change homepage to: "homepage": "./"
2. npm run build
3. re-upload these build files.